# Does it matter where I place noRollbackFor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

In Spring, if I have:

`ServiceA.serviceA() -> ServiceB.serviceB() -> ServiceC.serviceC() ->ServiceD.serviceD()`

where `ServiceD.serviceD()` can throw a runtime exception: `MyRuntimeException`, which is propagated back up to `ServiceA.serviceA` catch block.  Does it matter on which service I put `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=[MyRuntimeException.class])` on?

Is there any difference between putting it on any of the services?

Note: All my Services are marked as @Transactional

Comment: From your question, I am guessing all your service methods (A -> D) are transactional and you need to decide from a long call of transactional methods where to handle a certain exception. If all those methods are `@Transactional` (AND your calls are actually performed on the proxied version of that service, meaning no internal calls or things like that that break the proxy mechanism) I would say that you need to place the `noRollbackFor` on the ServiceD method.

Comment: Are all methods `@Transactional`?

Comment: @Andrei Stefan, I have updated question.  Do I have to put in D, what happens if I only want to not rollback for this particular flow?

Comment: Does any of the services catch the Exception, or is it propagated all along the chain ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you did not give precision on that, I assume that you are using default propagation of `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`. In that context, the 4 services will use the same transaction, and if any of the three inner marks the transaction as read-only as a result of the exception, the outer will get a `UnexpectedRollbackException`  to inform it that the asked commit actually resulted in a rollback. From Spring Reference Manual : *However, in the case where an inner transaction scope sets the rollback-only marker, the outer transaction has not decided on the rollback itself, and so the rollback (silently triggered by the inner transaction scope) is unexpected. A corresponding UnexpectedRollbackException is thrown at that point. This is expected behavior so that the caller of a transaction can never be misled to assume that a commit was performed when it really was not. So if an inner transaction (of which the outer caller is not aware) silently marks a transaction as rollback-only, the outer caller still calls commit. The outer caller needs to receive an UnexpectedRollbackException to indicate clearly that a rollback was performed instead.*. And if the outer transaction decides to rollback the transaction because of the exception, the transaction will obviously be rolled back.

So if none of the services catches the exception, and if you use a propagation of `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`, at least the four involved methods have to be annotated with `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=[MyRuntimeException.class])`.

An alternative of using `noRollbackFor=[MyRuntimeException.class]` would be to catch the exception in the appropriate method of `ServiceD`. In that case, the exception will never climb up the stack, and none of the transactional proxies will ever knows it occurred. The commit would then normally happen at the end of the transaction.

Edit per comment :

If you want further control on exception management, you could try to duplicate method : a transactional method, that calls a non transactional one in your service class. And you could call the non-transactional one if you do not want another transactional proxy in the chain. But this has sense only if this use case (a service class calling another service class with special exception requirement) is exceptional.

As an alternative, you could inject the implementations on the other service classes instead of injecting the transactional proxies (`@Autowired private ServiceBImpl serviceB;`). As you are already have a transaction obtained at the outer level, all DAO operations should be fine, and as there is only one transactional proxy at the outer level, you have one single point of control for exception management. It is rather uncommon to inject classes instead of interfaces, and you should document the *why* in a red flashing font :-) , but it should meet your requirements.

Comment: Yes, all service methods have their proparagtion level set to `REQUIRED`. Shouldn't the outer transaction impose their restrictions on all its inner transations? For example, I have several transactional methods that will rollback on any raised runtime exceptions. And I want to perform and outer transaction for which it is okay to pass on some specific runtime exception that will call these rollback transactional methods inside. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a combination of

```
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = MyRuntimeException.class)
```

then this service can commit independently from the rollback of the parent transaction (which will occur if it is not annotated with `noRollbackFor`). Otherwise you would have to mark all the transactional methods involved with the same noRollbackFor annotation.